# Map cannot navigate foreign country

Tags: macos, maps

I cannot get my Map app on Mac OS X Yosemite to navigate a different country. For example, if I search for "Osaka, Japan", it kept finding me the nearly Japanese restaurant named Osaka...

How to get around this?

Comment: This applies to anything Apple Maps can't find [which is frequent]. Find it in Google Maps, then scroll out until you can identify its approximate location visually on both Apple & Google; then scroll back in until you can pinpoint the matching location. Drop a Pin. Unfortunately, Apple Maps has a long way to go to catch up [which I find especially irritating as it's the one I have to use on my CarPlay system]